# webViewDidFinishLoad with current url

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm developing an app but I can't get this function to work! The webView should load facebook.com/profile.php or something like that, and when the url is equal to facebook.com/profile.php then an alert should be loaded. The code I have right now gives the alert, even when not logged in. So the code should check if the user is on the profile page, and when the user is loggin in on facebook then the alert should be loaded when the profile.php is reached. I can't figure out to do so.. I think I should check for the current url when the webview did finish load but I can't get this to work.. This is my code:

```
 webView.delegate = self

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://m.facebook.com/profile.php?ref=bookmarks")!

    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))

    self.displayAlert("Download Complete", message: "Your Facebook Profile Viewers were succesfully found!")

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webview: UIWebView) {


        print("it worked")

       if let currentURL = webView.request?.URL!.absoluteString {


        print(currentURL)

    } else {


    }


    }

    task.resume()
```

any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Check the current URL with the one you are intending! What's the problem???

Comment: The code isn't calling the webViewDidFinishLoad, so the url doesn't get checked and the 'it worked' isn't printed..

Comment: Could you see the Facebook page loaded on the we view on your screen??

Comment: Yes the webview is loaded properly, everything functions except for the webViewDidFinishLoad..